# $http.jsonp - unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, jsonp

I'm able to get a response from the request but the .then() part of my code doesn't fire. What am I doing wrong?

```
window.distance24Result = function(data){ alert(data.distance); };
$http.jsonp("http://www.distance24.org/route.jsonp?stops="+city+"|"+country,{data:'jsonp',
jsonpCallbackParam: 'distance24Result'
})
.then(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

Comment: Check the response from the server - it is likely that you have an error on the server side.

Comment: it is further more likely you are getting HTML response from that URL

Comment: Correct, it is HTML. How do I make it JSON?

Comment: You can't make it json, unless you are the owner of the server. The problem is that it seems like the output should be json, so check if the request is correct.

Comment: I noticed that the url had "jsonp" in it so I changed it to "json" and now I'm getting a JSON response but it says the unexpected token is ':'

Comment: @AaronFeigenbaum — You need a JSONP response not a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [the docs](http://www.distance24.org/api.xhtml), you'll have to pass `jsonp` as the [`jsonpCallbackParam`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) so that Angular uses the correct request url. It's the name of the GET parameter, not the name of the callback function. Also, the path is `route.json` not `route.jsonp`.

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.distance24.org/route.json?stops="+city+"|"+country, {
    jsonpCallbackParam: 'jsonp'
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(data.distance);
});
```

Alternatively, you can also use

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.distance24.org/route.json", {
    params: {stops: city+"|"+country},
    jsonpCallbackParam: 'jsonp'
})
```

---

Before Angular v1.6, there was no `jsonpCallbackParam` config value. Instead you'd use

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.distance24.org/route.json?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK&stops="+city+"|"+country)
```

or

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.distance24.org/route.json", {params: {
    "stops": city+"|"+country,
    "jsonp": "JSON_CALLBACK"
}})
```

Comment: Tried both ways and it says the unexpected token is ':'

Comment: What is the URL your browser console shows you for the request?

Comment: Oh. Which Angularjs version are you using? I only looked at the latest docs.

Comment: Ah, turns out I'm using 1.5.7 Thanks a ton man! Everything's working now.